# Bootstrap's dropdown menu disappears after two clicks

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing issue with Bootstrap based dropdown menu (nothing fancy, just a navigation). Everything works smoothly, but when I want to collapse the dropdown by clicking on it, it disappears, yet shows up when I hover or click it again. I have read some threads about stopPropagation() function but it still does not work. Here is my code.

```
                        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="Matt O'Such">

        <title></title>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

        <style>
        body { 
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8), rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)), url("images/background-homepage.jpg");
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8), rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)), url("images/background-homepage.jpg");
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8), rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)), url("images/background-homepage.jpg");
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8), rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)), url("images/background-homepage.jpg");
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)), to(rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8))), url("images/background-homepage.jpg");
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8), rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)), url("images/background-homepage.jpg");
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/background-homepage.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/background-homepage.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a
        {
        color:#e6e6e6;
        font-size:11px;
        padding-top:22px;
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
        color:#f9f9f9;
        background:#2f2b2e;
        border-bottom:2px solid #bfff51;
        font-size:11px;
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover{
        color:#f9f9f9;
        background:#2f2b2e;
        border-bottom:2px solid #bfff51;
        font-size:11px;
        }

        .dropdown-menu>li>a {
        display: block;
        padding: 3px 20px;
        clear: both;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        color: #fefefe;
        white-space: nowrap;
        background:#4c4649;
        font-size:11px;
        }

        .dropdown-menu {
        position:absolute;
        padding:0px;
        border-radius:0px;
        border:0px;
        min-width:0;
        background:red;font-size:11px;

        }

        .wrapper {
        }

        .homepage-welcome {
        font-family:Lobster;
        font-size:2em;
        color:#fefefe;}

        .homepage-title{
        font-family:'Open Sans';
        font-size:3em;
        color:#fefefe;}
        }

        </style>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //$(".nav li").removeClass("active");
            $('.menu-item-home').addClass('active');
            //for demo
            //$('#demo').addClass('active');
            //for sale 
            //$('#sale').addClass('active');
            $('.dropdown-menu input').click(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="border-radius:0px;background:none;border:0px;">
                <div class="container-fluid" style="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                            </button>
                            <a title "Matt's portfolio - go to homepage" style="margin-left:20px;margin-top:2px;" class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#"><img alt="Matt's portfolio logo" src="images/wm-logo.png" /></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="text-transform:uppercase;margin-right:20px;">
                                <li class="menu-item-home">
                                    <a href="/home">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Projects <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                      <li><a href="/projects/graphics">Graphics</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="/projects/websites">Websites</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="/projects/others">Others</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/about">About</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                        <h3 class="homepage-welcome">My name is Matt and this is my portfolio. </h3>
                    <h1 class="homepage-title">I make the Internet a better place.</h1>
                    <p>Passionate about People. Targeted on feelings and relationships. <br />Charmed by modern, frontend technologies.</p>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>      
</body>
```

Comment: your code is not clear what's the problem. you may have to share your full code with. however you can try to change JQuery version. it may cause problems.

Comment: edited first post, please find there full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code and ques is not much clear, but I still try to answer your question based on some understanding which might be the ans of your ques.

Case-1:

I think you don't want to hide the dropdown menu while clicking on any of the item of dropdown menu, as you have written some scripts for this.
But you have added '**input**' tag which should not be there as there is no 'input' tags inside the dropdown menu.
Use the below script,

```
 $('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {

         e.stopPropagation();
   });
```

Case-2:

If you don't want to hide the dropdown menu on clicking of dropdown button, just remove the '**data-toggle**' attribute as it will toggle the dropdown menu every time you click on button.

```
<li class="dropdown" id="dropDownBtn">
     <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Projects <span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="/projects/graphics">Graphics</a></li>
         <li><a href="/projects/websites">Websites</a></li>
         <li><a href="/projects/others">Others</a></li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

and add the below script,

```
 $("#dropdownBtn").on('click',function(){

            $(this).parent().addClass('open');
 });

$(document).on('click',function(el){
    if(el.target.id != "dropdownBtn"){ //give some condition which suits your code

                $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
            }
});
```

case-3:
As you have mentioned that, you wanted to collapse the dropdown by clicking on it. I don't get this point, as this is the normal behaviour of bootstrap.
But if you wanted that dropdown shown only once, then you can use **one()** method in the case-2

```
$("#dropdownBtn").one('click',function(){

            $(this).parent().addClass('open');
 });
```

Let me know which case suits you, also if both of the above mentioned cases doesn't help you, then please clear the ques, I would be thankful to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            //$(".nav li").removeClass("active");
            $('.menu-item-home').addClass('active');
            //for demo
            //$('#demo').addClass('active');
            //for sale 
            //$('#sale').addClass('active');
            $('.dropdown-menu input').click(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
            });
        </script>
```

```css
 body { 
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8), rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)), url("images/background-homepage.jpg");
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8), rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)), url("images/background-homepage.jpg");
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8), rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)), url("images/background-homepage.jpg");
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8), rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)), url("images/background-homepage.jpg");
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)), to(rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8))), url("images/background-homepage.jpg");
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8), rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)), url("images/background-homepage.jpg");
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/background-homepage.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/background-homepage.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a
        {
        color:#e6e6e6;
        font-size:11px;
        padding-top:22px;
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
        color:#f9f9f9;
        background:#2f2b2e;
        border-bottom:2px solid #bfff51;
        font-size:11px;
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover{
        color:#f9f9f9;
        background:#2f2b2e;
        border-bottom:2px solid #bfff51;
        font-size:11px;
        }

        .dropdown-menu>li>a {
        display: block;
        padding: 3px 20px;
        clear: both;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        color: #fefefe;
        white-space: nowrap;
        background:#4c4649;
        font-size:11px;
        }

        .dropdown-menu {
        position:absolute;
        padding:0px;
        border-radius:0px;
        border:0px;
        min-width:0;
        background:red;font-size:11px;

        }

        .wrapper {
        }

        .homepage-welcome {
        font-family:Lobster;
        font-size:2em;
        color:#fefefe;}

        .homepage-title{
        font-family:'Open Sans';
        font-size:3em;
        color:#fefefe;}
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="border-radius:0px;background:none;border:0px;">
                <div class="container-fluid" style="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                            </button>
                            <a title "Matt's portfolio - go to homepage" style="margin-left:20px;margin-top:2px;" class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#"><img alt="Matt's portfolio logo" src="images/wm-logo.png" /></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="text-transform:uppercase;margin-right:20px;">
                                <li class="menu-item-home">
                                    <a href="/home">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Projects <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                      <li><a href="/projects/graphics">Graphics</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="/projects/websites">Websites</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="/projects/others">Others</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/about">About</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                        <h3 class="homepage-welcome">My name is Matt and this is my portfolio. </h3>
                    <h1 class="homepage-title">I make the Internet a better place.</h1>
                    <p>Passionate about People. Targeted on feelings and relationships. <br />Charmed by modern, frontend technologies.</p>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>      
</body>
```

it's working fine here as you see
check Your JQuery